# R CMD BATCH or Rscript with stop on error

Tags: r

I don't think `R CMD BATCH` or `Rscript` is supposed to stop on an error, but I would like it to (or something like it).

As an example I have this in `test.R`:

```
stop("I really mean stop!")
cat("no, I dont want this printed")
```

After running `R CMD BATCH test.R`, I get:

```
> > stop("I really mean stop!") Error: I really mean stop!
> > 
> > cat("no, I dont want this printed") no, I dont want this printed>
```

The `cat` command is executed, even though I don't want it to be.

I've discovered a trick to make a file like `runTest.R` that contains

```
source('test.R')
```

And then if I run `R CMD BATCH runTest.R` things work as I like.

But I'm looking for a way that's not a trick and where I don't have to create an extra file.

Comment: Hmmm... I cannot reproduce this issue (Linux with R 3.0.3). Both `R CMD BATCH` and `Rscript` halt on error.

Comment: @gagolews Same here. (Arch linux with R 3.1.0)

Comment: I get the same results (execution halted without printing the second line) on windows.  Can we get the output of `sessionInfo()` and `getOption("error")`

Comment: On Windows it stops at the error for me with R 3.1.0 on both Rscript and R CMD BATCH.

Comment: Thank for your all the feedback guys. I figured it must have something to do with my `.Rprofile` and indeed it is due to `options(error = utils::dump.frames)`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Note that I posted a follow up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329178/why-is-behavior-in-r-cmd-batch-different-for-optionserror-utilsdump-frames

Answer (score 1):

If I remove the following from my `.Rprofile` I do not have the problem:

```
options(error = utils::dump.frames)
```

Thanks to the commenters for helping me figure that out.