# Why is behavior in R CMD BATCH different for options(error = utils::dump.frames)?

Tags: r

This is a followup to this question: [R CMD BATCH or Rscript with stop on error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327746/r-cmd-batch-or-rscript-with-stop-on-error/23329069#23329069)

If in my .Rprofile I have

```
options(error = utils::dump.frames)
```

then R CMD BATCH does not stop on errors.

If I run `R CMD BATCH` on a file containing the following:

```
stop("I really mean stop!")
cat("no, I dont want this printed")
```

The `cat` command is still executed.

But when I do `source` on that file, R stops. Why is this true and how do I make the behavior consistent?

Comment: Did you "source" from RStudio or an R shell with the error handler installed in `.Rprofile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Regarding the first part of your question:**

`?dump.frames` says:

*"If dump.frames is installed as the error handler, execution will continue even in non-interactive sessions. See the examples for how to dump and then quit."*

That's why `R CMD BATCH` does not stop on errors.

If you want to stop execution too then use (taken from the help example above!):

```
## A possible setting for non-interactive sessions
options(error = quote({dump.frames(to.file = TRUE); q(status = 1)}))
```

**2. Regarding the second part of your question (code example with `stop`):**

I suppose your dump.frames error handler is active too since to entered it into your `.Rprofile` and therefore the code execution continues for the reason explained above.

**3 Why does R stop immediately when sourcing the same code?**

Sorry, no idea (so my answer reamins incomplete for now)

**4. How do I make the behavior consistent?**

By using the error handler of 1.) above the code will always stop in case of an error.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I'm still interested in question 3 if you arrive at solution in future.

Comment: How do you source the file with the example code above? Using RStudio ("source" button or via console command?) or RScript using a starter script...? I think stop means stop and the unexpected behaviour is when R does not stop due to an error (which may be caused by an error handler set via `options(error = ...`). Add a line `getOption("error")` at the beginning of the sourced file to see the active error handler. Using Ubuntu 14.04 and RStudio the script stops at `stop` when I press the source button or source via console command.

Comment: I source just from terminal. I use R in gnome-terminal on Ubuntu. Thanks for continued insight.